# How can I find the probability distribution function from the observed data to use in a Monte Carlo Simulation?

Tags: distributions, density-function, monte-carlo, density-estimation

In exploring a data set, I think I've found an interesting instance where using a Monte Carlo method to plot a simulated group of points could yield somewhat accurate results.

The plotted data looks like this:
[image]

The trigonometric pattern is easy to see, and upon further observation, one can see that the points are not uniformly distributed in any given portion of the plot: areas closer to the bottom have a higher density of points than at the top of the pattern.

This leads me to my question: if I want to properly implement a Monte Carlo Method, how can I do so taking this difference of density into consideration? My understanding is that I have to use a probability distribution function (PDF) in generating the random points. How can I figure out the PDF from the observed data below?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let's back up: what do these data mean and what questions do you hope your "Monte Carlo Method" will answer about them?  These appear to be time series data with seasonality--not "trigonometic" data--suggesting a very different set of analytical approaches than the ones you outline.

Comment: @whuber The y-axis is sales (transformed logarithmically), and the x-axis is the year. I've already used time series analysis (both ARIMA and TBATS), but I was hoping to simulate data based on random generation, purely for curiosity's sake.

Comment: That's what's so puzzling: since in the use of both ARIMA and TBATS you have already fit models to the data, why aren't you using those models to generate data?

Comment: @whuber ...I already did use those models (in R). I'm just curious how one could use a simulation as an alternative method- again, purely for curiosity's sake.
If there's a (rigorous) argument as to why a MCM would be a really poor forecasting method with regards to my example, I'd be willing to read why.

Comment: You're basically saying you're looking for a third model but you're not giving us any motivation for the search or much guidance concerning the properties the model should have.  We have learned from your comments that the data have important structures that must be addressed in any model, such as the facts that the points are spaced equally in the x-coordinate, with just one observation each. That already indicates the approaches outlined in the question cannot possibly succeed at being "somewhat more accurate" unless they are refined to reflect these constraints.

Comment: @daOnlyBG you can use your model fit to simulate more data, in addition to the data you already have. This is one of the many uses of an estimated model. Also, Monte Carlo technique isn't just about simulating data. It involves using simulated data to esimate expectations.

Comment: @whuber Sorry- I didn't know that I needed others' motivation to ask how to figure out a PDF on CV- and I certainly didn't think a MCM would be **more** accurate than a time series analysis in this case. I really just wanted to experiment with MCMs, and seeing that I could use some constraints such as g(x) = mx+b and f(x) = |sin(x)|+g(x) could help outline the pattern we see in the chart. I really just wanted to compare results. If this is not the place to ask how to generate random numbers to fit some sort of pattern, then I respectfully defer to your suggestion for a better resource.